# Always be 100% bright when I'm using battery

Tags: battery, screen

When I'm using battery only - Ubuntu turns in some mode, when If I do not use my PC for about 5-10 seconds - the screeen becomes darker.

Where do turn this option off? Because I often need to read (without pressing keys and moving my mouse) and I can't see with dark screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### 11.10

Open System settings. Then, click the `Screen` option, and uncheck the `Dim screen to save power` box:

[image]

And you're done!

### 11.04

Open `gnome-power-preferences` - to do that, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then type in `gnome-power-preferences`. You'll see something like this:

[image: gnome-power-preferences on the AC Power Tab]

Go to the "On Battery Power" tab, then you'll want to make sure that the "Reduce Background Brightness" box isn't checked:

[image: gnome-power-preferences on the Battery Power Tab]

That should do the trick.

Comment: @Innuendo You're welcome! Glad to help. :)

Comment: This doesn't work in 11.10, so I've asked another question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74959/how-to-keep-a-bright-screen-with-battery-power-in-11-10