# How to keep a bright screen with battery power?

Tags: 11.10, power-management, screen, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Always be 100% bright when I'm using battery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33457/always-be-100-bright-when-im-using-battery)

It would seem that one would go to the power settings, and adjust the amount of time before the screen becomes dim, but unlike the nice images displayed in [Always be 100% bright when I'm using battery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33457/always-be-100-bright-when-im-using-battery), my power settings have no options for the length of time until the screen dims.

Here's what my power settings look like:

[image: power settings]

How can I prevent the 10-seconding dimming screen, when on battery power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Screen in options in System Settings and remove the tick mark in Dim Display

[image]

Comment: Not working for ubuntu 13.10